# IndexError: tuple index out of range to split features and label

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I got an error when trying to split features and label from DATASET. Here is the code:

```
print("Persiapan data")
#Split features and label from DATASET 
X = [] #features
Y = [] #labels
x_train,y_train=[],[]
for features,label in vektor_input:
    X.append(features)
    Y.append(label)
    
#Split X,Y to train and test
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, train_size=0.7)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], 1, x_test.shape[1]))


print("Ukuran x_train :",len(x_train))
print("Ukuran x_test  :",len(x_test))
```

the error shows. i'm new in python. please help, i've tried to fix it, but got some errors and stuck on this.

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-12-cd5441347f88> in <module>
      12 
      13 x_train = np.array(x_train)
 ---> 14 x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
      15 x_test = np.array(x_test)
      16 x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], 1, x_test.shape[1]))
  IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `x_train` and `y_train` are arrays, right? so the shape has one dimension not 2.

Comment: yes that is arrays. Ok i'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say np_array is a 1D array.

when using np_array.shape of a you will get output as ->  ( number of rows , )
so np_array.shape[1] gives you error "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

To solve this use an integer value instead of np_array.shape[1] as needed. ( Note: Total number of elements in input and output arrays should be same)

eg:

```
num = 2 # change this according to required output 
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (int(x_train.shape[0]/num), 1, num))
```

Comment: That's actually work, thanks!. but if i change 'the num = 2' to 3 output and I got error again. ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 52 into shape (17,1,3).
why ?

Comment: What is shape of x_train you are dealing with?  @futomo

Comment: my x_train.shape (48,5200)

Comment: In your question input x_train is 1D array right? then it should have shape as (number of rows , )

Comment: You would have to modify the code according to input shape and output shape.      refer: [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)